# Issues with HandlerMethod in annotation interceptor

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
public class AnnotationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter implements InitializingBean {
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        Api methodAnnotation = method.getMethodAnnotation(Api.class);

        if (methodAnnotation != null) {
            //..
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me: `'HandlerMethod cannot be resolved to a type'`

Haven't been able to track down any read up as to why.

Comment: Did you `import` the `HandlerMethod` class?

Comment: have these `import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
`

Comment: that would do it . `org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod` added and seems to have resolved that error. how do I mark your suggestion as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following import:

```
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
```

Comment: for those needing more info. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html